# How to print output of two shell commands on the same line?

Tags: bash, unix

This is what my loop contains:

```
cat /$f/stat | awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$7,$17}' /$f/stat 
cd $f 
sudo ls fd | wc -l  
cd ..
```

At first, it shows the output of:

```
cat /$f/stat | awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$7,$17}' /$f/stat
```

And it prints the output of this on a new line:

```
cd $f 
sudo ls fd | wc -l  
cd ..
```

How do I combine these so that it shows them on one line?

Comment: Note that awk won't read from stdin if filename arguments are present, meaning that `cat file | awk '...' file` is pointless.

Comment: If you don't want a newline to be printed, use `printf`.  Or just delete it after the fact with `tr`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `sudo ls fd | wc -l`? I suspect it is to determine if the file exists. Why are you using sudo though? If you can cd to the directory, you should be able to see the file even if you don't have any permissions to read/write/execute.

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, use [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to validate your script.

Looks like you want `awk`'s output and `wc -l`'s output to be on the same line.  Use command substitution for this:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$(awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$7,$17}' "$f/stat")" "$(sudo ls "$f/fd" | wc -l)"
```

- no need for `cat | awk` which is a case of [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) - `awk` is reading input from the file passed as an argument; also, it looks like you need `"$f/stat"` and not `"/$f/stat"`
- enclose variables in double quotes to prevent [word splitting and globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108963/201820)
- use full path `$f/fd` instead of having to do a `cd $f` and back

Since parsing `ls` output is considered a [bad practice](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you could do this instead, on Linux:

```
printf '%s %s\n' "$(awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$7,$17}' "$f/stat")" "$(sudo find "$f/fd" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | tr -cd '\0' | wc -c)"
```

- `find ... -print0` prints NUL terminated list of files
- `tr -cd '\0'` - deletes all characters other than NUL
- `wc -c` - counts the number of NULs, which is the number of file names in `find` output

---

Comment: I think it would be good to add `-1` option to ls, or use `find -maxdepth 1 "$f/fd"`

Comment: `ls` defaults to `-1` when the output is not being sent to terminal